# Sending QueryString in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am new to code Igniter framework, and I want to send querystring data, with $this->index(), function, how can i do this, I have done editing in config.php file, to accept query strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear at all. As an indication on how to work, though:

As it seems you already did, you must set to TRUE the "enable_query_string" config index:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

As you see, you also have an index for the $_GET array where controllers and models will be placed. In order to build a url (which **you must do manually,** since the helpers work with uri segments) you can do something like:

```
index.php?c=mycontroller&m=mymethod&var1=var1
```

which maps to `Mycontroller()` controller class and `Mymethod()` class method, and works the same as for uri segments. In your methods, to retrieve the query string variables after the method, you can:

1. use the `$this->input->get('var1')` input method to retrieve the query string part;
2. use the "regular" $_GET array (which you have enabled by passing TRUE to the config index, as above), `$_GET['var1']`
3. just pass the argument to the method (as in uri segments):

   ```
           function mymethod($var1)
           {
              echo $var1;
           {
   ```

"c" and "m" are default triggers, which you can obviously change to whatever you like (just set them in the 2 config indexes, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In Code Igniter you may use `$this->input->get()` inside your controller functions. You can also use PHP's `$_GET` array. More information in the documentation at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html